# Python's equivalent of Java's Set.add()?

Tags: java, python, set

Java's `Set.add` function will return a boolean value, which is `true` if the set did not already contain the specified element.

Python's `Set.add` does not have a return value.

Seems like in Python if I want to do the same thing, I have to check if it is in the set first and then add it if not.

Is there a simpler way to do that (preferably a one-liner)?

Ref:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#sets.Set

Comment: In python, if you add sometthing that's already in the set, it wont add a duplicate.

Comment: @pwnsauce: it won't in Java either. But the `Set.add()` method tells you if the element was already there, which can simplify code a little. Java needs all the help it can get when it comes to code simplicity, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a one-liner, you could use `or` to `add` the element only if it is not already `in` the set (short-circuit evaluation), and `not` to inverse the returned value and at the same time coerce to `bool`, turning the `None` returned by `add`, if it is called, into `True`, and otherwise just inverting the result of the `in` check:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> not(42 in s or s.add(42))
True
>>> not(42 in s or s.add(42))
False
>>> s
set([42])
```

However, since that one-liner might not be very easy to grasp, and you have to write the value to be inserted twice, you should probably make it a function, and then it does not matter much how many lines it uses.

```
def in_or_add(s, x):
    return not(x in s or s.add(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

No, Python's set implementation has no such method; as you noted you'll have to test for presence separately:

```
if obj not in setobj:
    setobj.add(obj)
```

or, what I usually do:

```
if obj in setobj:
    return  # or break out of a loop, etc.

# handle the case where the set doesn't have the object yet.
```

You can always subclass the `set` type:

```
class SetWithPresenceCheck(set):
    def add(self, value):
        not_present = value not in self
        super(SetWithPresenceCheck, self).add(value)
        return not_present
```

Note that the real reason `Set.add()` returns a boolean is to make adding and testing an *atomic operation*; implementations of the interface can (optionally) make the method synchronised and let callers avoid race conditions. Python's built-in set doesn't make any thread-safety promises *anyway*.

Comment: The problem with the Python approach is it forces a double lookup for each element that you're adding in the case where you have few (if any) duplicates in the input values. It's not a very expensive lookup normally, of course, but being able to hoist that into the actual implementation so that a single lookup is done would be a nice little efficiency boost.

Comment: @DonalFellows: that cost is negligible in the vast majority of cases, but if you are worried about it, and a benchmark shows that it would actually make a difference for your use cases, then you could use `oldlen = len(self)`, `super().add(value)`, `return len(self) > oldlen` as the `add` implementation in a subclass. The set length is O(1) lookup of a cached value updated each time the number of elements changes. I don't think it'll make a difference unless the `__hash__` implementation of your elements is costly and can't be cached, or the `__eq__` implementation is costly.

Comment: @DonalFellows: again, the primary reason that Java (and other languages, like Rust) return a bool (or the old value that was stored when updating a key-value pair in a map) is to support concurrency, not performance. Python is not a language built for speed, in any case, it is a language built for readability, maintainability, and development speed. By the time that double lookups in a set start to matter, you probably want to have moved the critical sections to a compiled language extension, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The union operator is much faster than add anyway.

```
>>> set_a = set('pqrs')
>>> set_b = ['t', 'u', 'v']
>>> set_a |= set(set_b)
>>> set_a
set(['p','q','r','s','t','u','v'])
```

Comment: A union won't tell you if the element was present before adding either. And why create a whole set if all you want to do is add **one** element?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: tue, but OP wants to add the element into set. Union will serve his purpose.

Comment: No, the OP wants to be told if an element was already present when adding in *one step*.

Comment: Ohh, yes. I should have read this question more carefully. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

maybe with ternary conditional operator :

```
the_set.add(what_ever) or True if what_ever not in the_set else False
```

This will return False if `what_ever` was in the set, True if it wasn't

Comment: This is invalid syntax. Assignment (`bool_already_in=True`) is a *statement*, not an expression, and can't be nested inside another expression.

Comment: So now you need to test for `None` or `False` in a separate statement. That's no more helpful than a separate containment check.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but you would have had to dothe same in `java : set.add()` no ? set.add() add the value if it isn't in the set and return True or False right ? Just like this

Comment: Besides, do you really think that an extended conditional expression like this is more readable and clearer?

Comment: Exactly, `Set.add()` returns a boolean value. You return either `False` (a boolean), or `None` (a false-y value). You can't use this in a `if` condition, you need to add `is None` or similar first.

Comment: That's what I am saying; no, it is not close enough. Even if it was, it is not actually useful, as it is unreadable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters now it's does return a real boolean... But okay it's ugly