# How can i remove overlap in list?

Tags: python

I made example python list.

```
list_1 = [1,3,2,2,3,4,5,1]
print(list_1)
```

> [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

To remove overlap, i tried to use set().

```
print(set(list_1))
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

but i want make

```
[1,3,2,4,5]
```

I want remove overlap in list, but i also want order not to be changed.

How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension with filter (initialize the empty list first, ignore the resulting list)

```
list_u = []
[list_u.append(v) for v in list_1 if v not in list_u]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could (ab)use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get just the unique elements in order:

```
>>> list_1 = [1,3,2,2,3,4,5,1]
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict((x, None) for x in list_1))
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a list comprehension with an additional `set` of already seen items. However, list comprehensions with side-effects are not considered best style.

```
>>> list_1 = [1,3,2,2,3,4,5,1]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in list_1 if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

The condition `not (x in seen or seen.add(x))` [works like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38563651/1639625): If `x in seen`, the `or` is true and thus the `not` is false, but if `x not in seen`, then the first part of the `or` is false, and thus the second part is executed and returns `None`, which is then converted to `True` by `not`.

Comment: Thanks for very kind explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```
seen = set()
result
for i in the_list:
  if i not in seen:
    seen.add(i)
    result.append(i)
```

I use `seen` for fast lookups, still unknown time complexity from the `result.append` method call.

It's possible to do this as a list comprehension as well, at the cost of mixing functional and imperative code in a horrible mish-mash:

```
seen = set()
def process(e):
  seen.add(e)
  return e
[process(element) for element in the_list if element not in seen]
```

But! This relies on side-effects in the mapping, so it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

To have distinct values in your list, just use the following snippet:

```
l = [1,3,2,2,3,4,5,1]
result = list()
map(lambda x: not x in result and result.append(x), l)
print(result) #[1,3,2,4,5]
```

As you already found out, `set()` doesn't preserve the order of your sequence. The basic idea is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459703/how-to-make-lists-distinct).

---

As tobias_k mentioned in the comment, this solution won't work with Python 3. If you use Python 3, you may just iterate through your list with a simple for loop (tobias_k's idea) or use libraries like `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([1,3,2,2,3,4,5,1]))
```

Comment: IMHO using a plain old `for` loop would be more pythonic than using `map` for side-effects. Also, this won't work in Python 3.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the comment mate. I agree with you. This isn't the pythonic way to go. But as I'm seeing right now, you also thought of the OrderedDict as a solution :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try This You can do this using reversing a `list`.without using any python libraries.

```
>>> list_1 = [1,3,2,2,3,4,5,1]
>>> list_1.reverse()
>>> for i in list_1:
...     if(list_1.count(i)>1):
...        list_1.remove(i)
... 
>>> list_1.reverse()
>>> list_1
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```